# what's wrong with this decorator

Tags: python, function, decorator

this is my decorator function, it should only check validation like email is valid, and password length is above 8 but I can't understand what is wrong

```
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapper_function(*args, **kwargs):
        user_email = kwargs.get("email", '')       
        user_password = kwargs.get("password", "")
        if user_email[-10:] == "@gmail.com" and len(str(user_password)) <= 8:
            func(**kwargs)
        else:
            print("user email is not valid")

    return wrapper_function
```

here is the login function, this function only checks the user email and password nothing else ,,,
can you help me why this not working

```
@my_decorator
def login(email, password):
    time.sleep(5)
    if email == user["email"] and password == user['password']:
        print(f"welcome {user['name']}")
    else:
        print("invalid user")


email = input("please type email - ")
password = input("please type password - ")

login(email, password)
```

Comment: For one thing you're not passing any keyword arguments.

Answer (score 2):

In your decorator you expect to receive email and password in `**kwargs`. However, only named (aka keyword) arguments are stored inside `**kwargs` while positional arguments are contained inside `*args`.

When you call your `login` function you pass the arguments in a positional maner, so the arguments are positional. If you want them to appear as named arguments you can do it the following way:

```py
login(email=email, password=password)
```

In this way the arguments are named arguments and will be stored in `**kwargs`, thus, your decorator will see them and process as expected.